# Retornar maior campo para o ID

Tags: sql, oracle

Bom dia, preciso de uma orientação referente a seguinte situação:

[image: SQL]

Nessa tabela preciso retornar apenas o MAX(nutab) para cada codprod e controle.
tentei utilizando o MAX, mas assim só retornou o que é igual a 80 que seria o max(nutab)... o problema é que tenho mais produtos nessa tabela e por exemplo o MAX(nutab) do produto 210 é 80, porem o do produto 211 já é 76, dessa forma não consigo retornar todos os dados apenas com o MAX(nutab).

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```sql
SELECT codprod, MAX(nutab)
FROM tabela
GROUP BY codprod
```

Comment: dessa forma não da certo, pois ai ele só vai me retornar os produtos que possuam o MAX = 81, o que não são todos os produtos... cada produto tem um MAX diferente.

Comment: No caso o produto 210 tem o MAX = 81, já o produto 211 tem o MAX = 76, se fazer da forma acima só irá retornar os registros com o MAX = 81

Comment: O código que eu coloquei está agrupando por codprod. Vai pegar o `MAX(nutab)` pra cada `codprod`. Não é isso o que vc precisa?

Comment: Também não entendi porque só retorna `max = 81`. Acredito que esta resposta resolva

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi de sua pergunta você quer agrupar os máximos valores de NUTAB em grupos de CODPROD.
Para isso SQL tem o GROUP BY, ele agrupa os campos e se utilizado junto ao MAX ele pode retornar o que você deseja.
Acredito que o que você procura seja algo como:

```
SELECT codprod, controle, vlrvenda, MAX(nutab) FROM suaTabela GROUP BY codprod, controle;
```

Dessa forma os valores serão retornados em três campos o CODPROD, o CONTROLE e o outro o maior NUTAB para estes valores de CODPROD e CONTROLE.

Mais informações sobre o GROUP BY: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

GROUP BY em multiplas colunas : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns

Comment: Dessa forma até da certo, o problema é que eu preciso retornar o campo vlrvenda na consulta também... com esse agrupamento já não da certo

Comment: Bom para isso é só adicionar o vlrvenda entre as colunas selecionadas. Vou atualizar a resposta para você ver se é o que você procura.

Answer (score 0):

consegui da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT
   A.controle,
   A.codprod,
   A.vlrvenda
FROM
   TGFEXC A
LEFT JOIN
   TGFEXC B
   ON  A.codprod = B.codprod
   AND B.nutab > A.nutab
where 
B.nutab IS NULL
```

Obrigado a todos!